# How to access asp.net mvc property in javascript method? using AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, methods, properties

i have a property `Model.Feeds`

i would like to add value to `Feeds` in javascript metod:

```
function DataRetrieved(data) {
            '<%=Model.Feeds %>' = data;
        }
```

`'<%=Model.Feeds %>'`  not works because its will be recognized as string.

please help how to access property of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model property is a server-side property. JavaScript runs on the client side. Thus, you cannot assign a value to your Model by using JavaScript. You have to set Model properties server-side.

Why are you trying to set a Model value within JavaScript? There might be another way to look at the problem, in order to come up with a solution.

Comment: i receiving data from server usind ajax request, iam getting value on client site, and need to show it in my model.feeds.

Comment: i did it so:  document.getElementById('feed').innerHTML = data;